# Use docker command in jenkins container

Tags: docker, jenkins

[My centos version and docker version（install by yum）](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C3W0c.png)

[Use docker common error in container](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r4Rfe.png)

My docker run command:

```
docker run -it -d -u root --name jenkins3 -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -v $(which docker):/usr/bin/docker docker.io/jenkins/jenkins
```

**but，its error when I exec docker info in jenkins container**

/usr/bin/docker: 2: .: Can't open /etc/sysconfig/docker

Comment: what is the problem you are facing? You have to be clear about it. One common process is to read your question from a stranger's perspective and to ask yourself is it clear enough.

Comment: @shakhawat I have make a supplemen,you  can also see the images

Comment: In general, just "copying" an application's binary to another computer is not enough to run that application. Did you follow some tutorial for this? Try installing docker-ce inside your container using yum.

Comment: @sneep install docker-ce is work but it make my image size very big，1.2G. I have read many turtorial , some only mount /var/run/docker.sock work,some also mount /usr/bin/docker work,I dont understand why mine is error.

Comment: Please don't paste screen shots of terminal windows into Stack Overflow questions; they're difficult to read and search later.  Instead, copy the relevant text out of your terminal window and paste it (possibly indented by four spaces, so it looks like a code block) into your question.

Answer (score 0):

Exposing the host's docker socket to your jenkins container will work with

```
-v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
```

but you will need to have the docker executable installed in your jenkins image via a Dockerfile.

It is likely the example you are looking at is already using a docker image. A quick google search brings up https://jpetazzo.github.io/2015/09/03/do-not-use-docker-in-docker-for-ci/ whose example uses a docker image (already has the executable installed):

```
docker run -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
       -ti docker
```

Also note from that same post your exact issue with mounting the binary:

> Former versions of this post advised to bind-mount the docker binary from the host to the container. This is not reliable anymore, because the Docker Engine is no longer distributed as (almost) static libraries.